# ActionScript3 dictionaries

Tags: actionscript-3, dictionary

In AS3, i want to have an associative array of type [Point] ---> [Shape], that associates various shapes with points in space. I would like to have this behaviour:

```
var dict : Dictionary = new Dictionary();
var pos : Point = new Point(10, 10);
dict[pos] = new Shape();
var equalPos : Point = new Point (pos.X, pos.Y);
dict[equalPos]  // <-- returns undefined and not the shape i created before because equalPos reference is different from pos.
```

I'd like to have `dict[equalPos]` to return the same as `dict[pos]` because the points, while different in references, are equal as coordinates (equal as class members).

Is there any way i can achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the key of dictionary,use the point' x and y

```
var key:String = point.x + "_" + point.y;//you could define a function to get key;

dict[key] = new Shape();
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe you can do this the way you want to.

I believe what you need to do is create a helper function.  (I had this same problem trying to compare points in Unit Tests)

So here, using psuedo code is what I would do.

```
public static function comparePoint(point1:Point, point2:Point):Boolean{
    return (poin1.x == poin2.x && point1.y == point2.y)? true:false;
}

private function findShapeInPointDictionary(dict:Dictionary, point:Point):Shape
{
     var foundShape:Shape = null;
     for (var dictPoint:Point in dict) {
         if(comparePoint(dictPoint, point) {
       foundShape = dict[dictPoint];
         }
     }
     return foundShape;

 }
}
```

Your example code might end up looking like this

```
var dict : Dictionary = new Dictionary();
var pos : Point = new Point(10, 10);
dict[pos] = new Shape();
var equalPos : Point = new Point (pos.X, pos.Y);
recievedShape = findShapeInPointDictionary(dict, equalPos);
```

Comment: If you have time later i'd like to see your solution, thank you!

Comment: @Banex hope that helps.  Don't forget to unit test the code! :)